# How to handle Divide by zero Error in SQL query

Tags: sql

Running following sql query in sql server.

```
Select id, description, cost, price, ((price-cost)/price) as Margin
from item
```

I am getting this error message.

```
Msg 8134, Level 1, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Values in price and cost are more than zero even after substraction they are more than zero. Don't understand why I am getting error message.

Comment: If items can never logically have a zero price, then consider using `NULL` for an unassigned price.

Comment: `where price > 0` perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nullif(price,0)`

```
Select id, description, cost, price, (price-cost)/nullif(price,0) as Margin from item
```

Answer (score 0):

try using NULL Functions
use NULIF(price,0)